# KendoAutoComplete - Selecteditem Id

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Using KendoAutoComplete control and binding values from the database.

Then when I try to retrieve the value here I'm getting the selected text.

Can anyone advice me how to get the Id of the selected item?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Select` event which Selects drop-down list item and sets the text of the autocomplete.

```
// get a reference to the autocomplete widget
var autocomplete = $("autocomplete").data("kendoAutoComplete");

// selects by jQuery object
autocomplete.select(autocomplete.ul.children().eq(0));
```

http://docs.kendoui.com/documentation/api/web/autocomplete#select

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/autocomplete/events.html

**Edit:** try to handle `select` event

```
      $("#products").kendoAutoComplete({
                    dataSource: data,
                    select: onSelect
                    });
```

then :

```
  function onSelect(e) {
                        if ("kendoConsole" in window) {
                            var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item.index());
                            kendoConsole.log("event :: select (" + dataItem + ")" );
                        }
                    }
```

now you can get item's index , as in 2nd link

Comment: Still having the issue. I'm getting error like 'ul' undefined